# Hiding the internals of a structure

Tags: c, struct, abstraction, void-pointers

In an API, is there some advantage to using type `void *` as a handle to structures returned to the user (as opposed to using type `name_of_the_structure *` and just hiding the implementation)?

Comment: I don't think it has any advantage (unless you are trying to hack around with "polymorphic" structs, as I often do). It reduces type safety.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `void*` then the contents is a completely black box which the user can't know anything about. However you also loose some type safety, as the user of your API can pass *any* pointer to your function and you have no simple way of detecting if it's a correct pointer or not.

Fortunately, you don't actually *have* to completely hide the structure. You simply have a public header which is distributed with the API, which *declares* the structure, like

```
struct my_special_struct;
```

Then your functions can still be declared using pointers to that structure, and the user too, but the user have to use your functions do create the actual instances, and the user also can't use your structure to access internal fields or get its size using `sizeof`.

Comment: That's what I meant by "hiding the implementation".

Comment: @user2656304 Okay, then no there is no advantage of using `void*`.